# How to open by default the Bootstrap menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

I have a site with "Bootstrap 3.3.7" and I want the menu to be opened by default.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="#block-menuprincipal">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Menu principal</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i> Profils</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg"></i> Boutiques</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit"><i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Produits</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service"><i class="fas fa-sign-language fa-lg"></i> Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe"><i class="fas fa-users fa-lg"></i> Groupes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce"><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-lg"></i> Annonces</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article"><i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-lg"></i> Articles</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion"><i class="fas fa-comments fa-lg"></i> Discussions</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette"><i class="fas fa-utensils fa-lg"></i> Recettes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire"><i class="fas fa-map-signs fa-lg"></i> Itinéraires</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement"><i class="fas fa-calendar fa-lg"></i> Événements</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

how to tell bootstrap to open the menu by default ?

The path to open is `#block-menuprincipal .dropdown`

If I try the following code, Bootstrap or Drupal automatically deletes the class open :

```
$("#block-menuprincipal .dropdown").addClass('open');
```

I want to open with JS but I do not know the code :

```
$("#block-menuprincipal .dropdown").dropdown('show');
});
```

The code above does not work because the class open is added to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` normally she should be added to `<li class="dropdown">`

Here is the link of the page https://www.s1biose.com you have to click on the menu at the top left. The "Main Menu" should be opened by default.

**UPDATE**

After several tests, collapse causes the closing of the menu.

I added this code to open the menu after collapse, but it does not work :

```
$('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#block-menuprincipal .dropdown').dropdown('show');
})
```

[image]

Comment: where is `views-manage-menu`

Comment: @guradio It's a block on drupal. The menu must be open by default if this block is present

Comment: Which menu are you using? A custom menu? Or the Bootstrap menu?

Comment: @mathieu, check this fiddle that I've made just to try to exemplify your scenario and tell me what are the differences between it and your problem. Note that I've added an "id" to the main navbar and also the "views-manage-menu" class to it. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkc30pyt/9/)

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed jquery:

```js
$('#block-menuprincipal').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {  
    $(this).find(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#block-menuprincipal" aria-expanded="false">
            menu
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="block-menuprincipal" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Menu principal</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i> Profils</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg"></i> Boutiques</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit"><i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Produits</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service"><i class="fas fa-sign-language fa-lg"></i> Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe"><i class="fas fa-users fa-lg"></i> Groupes</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce"><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-lg"></i> Annonces</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article"><i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-lg"></i> Articles</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion"><i class="fas fa-comments fa-lg"></i> Discussions</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette"><i class="fas fa-utensils fa-lg"></i> Recettes</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire"><i class="fas fa-map-signs fa-lg"></i> Itinéraires</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement"><i class="fas fa-calendar fa-lg"></i> Événements</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I updated my question with a simpler code and a link to my site. I tested your code and it does not work for me.

Comment: Maybe its due to 'collapse' menu check my edited answer

Comment: "Show"  is used to add 'display: block' property to the element  in bootstrap, if you want to add 'show' class then add it to '.dropdown-menu' instead of  '.dropdown'

Comment: $("#navbar-collapse-first .dropdown .dropdown-menu").addClass('show');

Comment: My code does not work The idea is to open the menu after the collapse of collapse. What do you think ?

Comment: I have a last question. I have two menu. A menu `#block-menuprincipal` that appears on all my pages and a `.views-manage-menu` menu that appears if the current user is the author of the page. How to open `.views-manage-menu` first if it is present ?

Comment: You can check if .views-manage-menu exists in the page or not using jquery and then take action depends on it

Comment: if($(".views-manage-menu").length == 0) { open #block-menuprincipal menu } else { open  #block-menuprincipal }

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/bKvabG

```
$(function() {
   $('ul[class="navbar-nav"] li[class="dropdown"]').addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I updated my question with a simpler code and a link to my site. I tested your code and it does not work for me.